# Apache Camel, delete=false is ignored

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to copy one file from one directory into another.

Here is simple code:

```
class MyAwesomeRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        String fileName = "file:/Users/name/Desktop/?delete=false";
        String toFile = "file:/Users/name/Documents/";
        this.from(fileName).to(toFile);
   }
}
```

I noticed that anything I put in Desktop folder automatically moved to Documents, but at the same time I want to keep my file in Desktop folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I never use Apache Camel but I thing you are moving file from folder.Search about how to copy file.For more information:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
from("file:/Users/name/Desktop/?noop=true").to("file:/Users/name/Documents/");
```

You can check out this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074705/core-java/hello-camel--automatic-file-transfer.html) as well.

Comment: Yes use noop=true to leave the file as-is. By default Camel moves files to a sub folder named .camel. But noop=true will leave the file as-is

Comment: yes, its available in the tutorial i mentioned above.